# JScrollPane - content and Scrollbar not rendering

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I'm creating a small [Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) application. I'm using a 'dynamic universe' for all my cells (named Tiles in my project). But for some reason my `JScrollPane` and `JButtons` aren't rendering into the frame. I just get a empty JFrame. The controller is returning values and the buttons are getting constructed and added to the panel. It's just that `jsp.setViewportView(p);` doesn't seem to update the UI.

Main:

```
GOLController controller = new GOLController();
controller.run();
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
    GameOfLifeFrame frame = new GameOfLifeFrame(controller);
    frame.init();
});
```

UI class:

```
package org.gameoflife.ui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import org.gameoflife.controller.GOLController;
import org.gameoflife.model.Tile;

public class GameOfLifeFrame extends JFrame {

    private final GOLController controller;
    private JScrollPane jsp;

    public GameOfLifeFrame(GOLController controller) throws HeadlessException {
        super("Game of Life");
        this.controller = controller;
    }


    public void init() {
        jsp = new JScrollPane();
        add(jsp);

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        setVisible(true);

        controller.setLock();
        this.draw();
        controller.releaseLock();
    }

    public void draw(){
        List<List<Tile>> currentState = controller.getTiles();
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(currentState.size(), currentState.get(0).size());

        JPanel p = new JPanel(layout);
        currentState.stream().forEach((currentTiles) -> {
            currentTiles.stream().map((t) -> {
            JButton b=new JButton(" ");
            b.setBackground(t.isHasLife() ? Color.GREEN : Color.BLACK);
            return b;
            }).forEach((b) -> {
                p.add(b);
            });
        });
        jsp.removeAll();
        jsp.setViewportView(p);
    }

}
```

I'm probably overlooking something really stupid, any help is appreciated.

Comment: This `jsp.removeAll()` is going to be problematic, as it's likely removed the viewport, it's also no required, as setting the `viewportView` will do the samething anyway

Comment: sigh works :) thanks. Can you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: `jsp.removeAll()` is going to be problematic, as it's likely removed the viewport AND the `JScrollBar`s, it's also no required, as setting the `viewportView` will do the same thing anyway

Remember, `JScrollPane` is a specailsed component, that consists of a `JViewPort` and two `JScrollBar`s, the actually content lives on the `JViewport`, not the `JScrollPane`

[image: ScrollPane]